# How to create single dockerfile with node, yarn, python and maven

Tags: dockerfile

I'm trying to create a single dockerfile that includes npm, yarn, python, and mvn. Could anyone suggest the best practice to create a dockerfile with these packages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is my code, but it's not working.

FROM node
RUN npm install npm
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
RUN mv node_modules/npm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn --pure-lockfile

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python